# How to parse and get values from XML api response in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am getting xml response from api in PowerShell, can any one tell me how to loop through and read element values.

My api response

```
<tlp:Names xmlns:tlp="http://www.timelog.com/XML/Schema/tlp/v4_4">
<tlp:Name ID="12">
    <tlp:Project>ProjectA</tlp:ProjectID>
    <tlp:Task>TaskA</tlp:TaskID>
</tlp:Name>
<tlp:Name ID="13">
    <tlp:Project>ProjectB</tlp:ProjectID>
    <tlp:Task>TaskB</tlp:TaskID>
</tlp:Name>
<tlp:Name ID="17">
    <tlp:Project>ProjectC</tlp:ProjectID>
    <tlp:Task>TaskC</tlp:TaskID>
</tlp:Name>
<tlp:Name ID="14">
    <tlp:Project>ProjectD</tlp:ProjectID>
    <tlp:Task>TaskD</tlp:TaskID>
</tlp:Name>
```

</tlp:Names>

How to read project and task values from the xml data from the above response in powershell. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML is invalid.

The "Project" and "Tasks" elements are closed with "ProjectID" and "TasksID".
They must match.

As soon as you or the developer/admin fixes this, you can cast/parse the plain XML content to a XML document and use it like every other object in PowerShell (by property accessors).

Here as example with a valid XML:

```bsh
$xmlPlainText = @'
<tlp:Names xmlns:tlp="http://www.timelog.com/XML/Schema/tlp/v4_4">
    <tlp:Name ID="12">
        <tlp:Project>ProjectA</tlp:Project>
        <tlp:Task>TaskA</tlp:Task>
    </tlp:Name>
    <tlp:Name ID="13">
        <tlp:Project>ProjectB</tlp:Project>
        <tlp:Task>TaskB</tlp:Task>
    </tlp:Name>
    <tlp:Name ID="17">
        <tlp:Project>ProjectC</tlp:Project>
        <tlp:Task>TaskC</tlp:Task>
    </tlp:Name>
    <tlp:Name ID="14">
        <tlp:Project>ProjectD</tlp:Project>
        <tlp:Task>TaskD</tlp:Task>
    </tlp:Name>
</tlp:Names>
'@

$xmlDocument = [xml]$xmlPlainText

$xmlDocument.Names.Name
```